# PhpStorm: make find results hierarchical

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to show find results hierarchical in the Find Tool? Currently if occurrences are contained in a few files from the same folder we see a full path of each file. For example,

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/file1
/folder1/folder2/folder3/file2
/folder1/folder2/folder3/file3
```

So is it possible to show the results as a hierarchical list

```
/folder1
    /folder2
        /folder3
            file1
            file2
            file3
```

I hope this image illustrates what I mean.

[image]

Intention is if I know that `folder1` doesn't have anything I really look for (e.g. a `vendor` folder), just collapse the folder to hide from results.

Comment: Not at the moment. Feel free to submit the feature request to our tracking system here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA#newissue=yes

Comment: Submitted as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38540